# Set path environment variable in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 18.04, environment-variables, paths

By mistake, I changed the path environment variable in Ubuntu. 
Now when I turned my pc on, the login screen is coming and after entering my password and pressing enter, the screen goes away for a moment and again the login screen is coming.

When I enter any command in the terminal that comes after pressing Ctrl+alt+f3, the error displayed is : The command could not be located because /usr/bin is not included in the PATH environment variable.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Can I set the environment variables again?

Comment: *Where* did you change the variable? You can always run commands in the terminal using their full path - for example `/bin/nano` or `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: @steeldriver what should I do after that?

Comment: You should revert the mistake - it's hard to be more specific unless you give more information about what you did (edited the `/etc/environment` file? wrote a new `PATH` to your `~/.bashrc`?)

Comment: I edited the /etc/environment file.

Comment: OK so edit it back to default using `/usr/bin/sudoedit /etc/environment` or `/usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/environment`

Comment: What would be the solution if I wrote a new path to my ~/.bashrc?

Comment: Then you could do `/bin/nano ~/.bashrc` and either correct or comment out (by placing a `#` at the start) the new path that you added

Answer (score 0):

You say that you accidentally changed your path environment variable. In order to fix this problem correctly,  we need a little more information. What happened? How did you manage to change the path environment variable?

I have had a similar experience when the .Xauthority in my home directory mysteriously changed ownership to root.

Login as root and check ownership of your. Xauthority file

ls -l should show your user name something like this (assuming a username of "yourname"):

```
cd /home/yourname
ls -l .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 yourname yourname 270 Dec 23 03:00 .Xauthority
```

If it looks like the following, you will have trouble and a login loop:

```
cd /home/yourname
ls -l .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 root root 270 Dec 23 03:00 .Xauthority
```

If you see

```
ls -l .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 root root 270 Dec 23 03:00 .Xauthority
```

You will need to change ownership of .Xauthority back to your user account by this command:

```
chown yourname:yourname .Xauthority
```

Then log out of root or reboot and attempt to login by your user account.

Comment: I accidentally changed the path variable from the terminal.

Comment: I didn't see your answer until now because of the holidays.It is important to know what you typed in the terminal to know how to fix this problem or if a fix is needed beyond simply restarting the computer (If you didn't make changes to configuration files, restarting will cause your error to be "lost"). We need more information. What did you type?

You may also find the solution on the other forum stackoverflow useful:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix